# How to deploy a contract to Tezos Mainnet?

Tags: rpc, contract, deploy

I've searched a lot but it seems nothing works at this point

So I have a contract.liq source code. I also have up and running tezos-node. Basically the question is how to deploy contract.liq to the network using tezos-client (or anything else)?

I found:

```
tezos-client -A mainnet-node.tzscan.io originate contract
```

But it doesn't seem working:

```
Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.
```

I found the article https://medium.com/chain-accelerator/how-to-use-tezos-rpcs-16c362f45d64 but it describes how to make a transaction using RPC.

I'd be thankfull if anyone would help me!

Comment: Not sure if `.liq` is supported by it already but maybe have a look at Ligo;
https://ligolang.org/docs/intro/what-and-why/